# Run Command Prompt Code in Vb.net

Tags: vb.net, command-line, cmd, runcommand

I can run " Dism.exe /online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:E:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess " code in Command Prompt.

What I wan't to do is to run this code through Vb.net application.

Comment: btw this code should be run using administrator rights...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the `Process.Start` API to do this

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start( _
  "Dism.exe", _
  "/online /enable-feature /featurename:NetFX3 /All /Source:E:\sources\sxs /LimitAccess")
```

Note that you will possibly have to provide the full path to `dism.exe`